# C++ Multiconnection basic console tchat server Winsock2 Second client not receiving anything

Tags: c++, tcp, server, client, winsock2

EDIT : Server updated code

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

//Global values
//I put them as global values in order to get the server up and running.
//I will try to pass them as params later on
int iResult;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
int numClients = 0;
SOCKET ClientSocket[5];
std::thread** sendReceiveThread = new std::thread*[5];
bool firstTime = true;

//Prototypes
int listen(SOCKET ListenSocket);
int accept(SOCKET ListenSocket);
int sendReceive();
int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ClientSocket);

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "1016"

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


    // Initialize Winsock
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    listen(ListenSocket);

    return 0;
}

int listen(SOCKET ListenSocket)
{
    int numPort = 1;
    std::vector<std::thread*> thread_vec;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed with error : " << iResult << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    std::cout << 6 << std::endl;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << 7 << std::endl;
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    char optval = 1;
    iResult = ::setsockopt(ListenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 9 << std::endl;
        printf("setsockopt failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    std::cout << 8 << std::endl;
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 9 << std::endl;
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << 10 << std::endl;
        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << 11 << std::endl;
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        std::cout << 23 << std::endl;

        static std::thread AcceptThread{ [ListenSocket](){accept(ListenSocket); } };
        thread_vec.push_back(&AcceptThread);
    }
    for (auto it : thread_vec) it->join();
    return 0;
}

int accept(SOCKET ListenSocket)
{
    numClients++;
    const int currentNumClients = numClients;
    if (firstTime == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            ClientSocket[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        firstTime = false;
    }
    // Accept a client socket
    std::cout << 12 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 13 << std::endl;

    ClientSocket[currentNumClients] = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket[currentNumClients] == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Client " << currentNumClients << " connected" << std::endl;
    }

    sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients] = new std::thread([](){sendReceive(); });
    (*sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients]).join();
    delete sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients];

    return 0;
}

int sendReceive()
{
    int currentNumClients = numClients;
    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << 14 << std::endl;
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket[currentNumClients], recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        std::cout << iResult << std::endl;
        if (iResult > 0) {
            std::cout << 15 << std::endl;
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the clients
            std::cout << 16 << std::endl;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numClients; i++)
            {
                iSendResult = send(ClientSocket[currentNumClients], recvbuf, iResult, 0);
                if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    std::cout << 17 << std::endl;
                    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }
                printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
            }
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            std::cout << 18 << std::endl;
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << 19 << std::endl;
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            std::cout << "On client #" << currentNumClients << std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }

    iResult = shutdownFunction(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);

    std::cout << 22 << std::endl;
    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ClientSocket)
{
    std::cout << 20 << std::endl;
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 21 << std::endl;
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently proggramming a c++ server and client chatroom in the console using Winsock2. My problem is that the second time I launch the client, it seems to connect fine but the server doesn't seem to receive anything that it sends. One of the clients works fine and the other doesn't work.

Here is my server code :

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

//Global values
//I put them as global values in order to get the server up and running.
//I will try to pass them as params later on
int iResult;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
int numClients = 0;
SOCKET ClientSocket[5];
std::thread** sendReceiveThread = new std::thread*[5];

//Prototypes
int listen(SOCKET ListenSocket);
int accept(SOCKET ListenSocket);
int sendReceive();
int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ClientSocket);

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT1 "1016"
#define DEFAULT_PORT2 "1017"
#define DEFAULT_PORT3 "1018"
#define DEFAULT_PORT4 "1019"
#define DEFAULT_PORT5 "1020"

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


    // Initialize Winsock
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    listen(ListenSocket);

    return 0;
}

int listen(SOCKET ListenSocket)
{
    int numPort = 1;
    std::vector<std::thread*> thread_vec;
    while (true)
    {
        if (numPort == 1)
        {
            // Resolve the server address and port
            std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
            iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT1, &hints, &result);
            numPort++;
            if (iResult != 0) {
                std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
                printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
                WSACleanup();
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (numPort == 2)
        {
            // Resolve the server address and port
            std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
            iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT2, &hints, &result);
            numPort++;
            if (iResult != 0) {
                std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
                printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
                WSACleanup();
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (numPort == 3)
        {
            // Resolve the server address and port
            std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
            iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT3, &hints, &result);
            numPort++;
            if (iResult != 0) {
                std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
                printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
                WSACleanup();
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (numPort == 4)
        {
            // Resolve the server address and port
            std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
            iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT4, &hints, &result);
            numPort++;
            if (iResult != 0) {
                std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
                printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
                WSACleanup();
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (numPort == 5)
        {
            // Resolve the server address and port
            std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
            iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT5, &hints, &result);
            numPort++;
            if (iResult != 0) {
                std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
                printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
                WSACleanup();
                break;
            }
        }

        else if (numPort == 6)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        std::cout << 6 << std::endl;
        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cout << 7 << std::endl;
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        char optval = 1;
        iResult = ::setsockopt(ListenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << 9 << std::endl;
            printf("setsockopt failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket
        std::cout << 8 << std::endl;
        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << 9 << std::endl;
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        std::cout << 10 << std::endl;
        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << 11 << std::endl;
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            break;
        }

        std::cout << 23 << std::endl;

        static std::thread AcceptThread{ [ListenSocket](){accept(ListenSocket); } };
        thread_vec.push_back(&AcceptThread);
    }
    for (auto it : thread_vec) it->join();
    return 0;
}

int accept(SOCKET ListenSocket)
{
    numClients++;
    const int currentNumClients = numClients;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        ClientSocket[i] = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    std::cout << 12 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 13 << std::endl;

    ClientSocket[currentNumClients] = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket[currentNumClients] == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients] = new std::thread([](){sendReceive(); });
    (*sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients]).join();
    delete sendReceiveThread[currentNumClients];

    return 0;
}

int sendReceive()
{
    int currentNumClients = numClients;
    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << 14 << std::endl;
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket[currentNumClients], recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        std::cout << iResult << std::endl;
        if (iResult > 0) {
            std::cout << 15 << std::endl;
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            // Echo the buffer back to the clients
            std::cout << 16 << std::endl;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numClients; i++)
            {
                iSendResult = send(ClientSocket[currentNumClients], recvbuf, iResult, 0);
                if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    std::cout << 17 << std::endl;
                    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }
                printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
            }
        }
        else if (iResult == 0) {
            std::cout << 18 << std::endl;
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << 19 << std::endl;
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            std::cout << "On client #" << currentNumClients << std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }

    iResult = shutdownFunction(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);

    std::cout << 22 << std::endl;
    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket[currentNumClients]);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ClientSocket)
{
    std::cout << 20 << std::endl;
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 21 << std::endl;
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my clients code :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024
#define DEFAULT_PORT "1016"

//Prototypes
int sendFunction(char *sendbuf, SOCKET ConnectionSocket);
int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ConnectSocket);
int receiveFunction(SOCKET ConnectSocket, int recvbuflen);
int inputFunction(char *sendbuf, SOCKET ConnectSocket);

int main()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    #define IP "127.0.0.1"
    iResult = getaddrinfo(IP, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
        std::cout << 5 << std::endl;

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cout << 6 << std::endl;
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        std::cout << 7 << std::endl;
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << 8 << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    //Error management for the ConnectSocket
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << 9 << std::endl;
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ReceiveSocket = ConnectSocket;

    std::thread inputThread{ [sendbuf, ConnectSocket](){inputFunction(sendbuf, ConnectSocket); } };
    std::thread receiveThread{ [ReceiveSocket, recvbuflen](){receiveFunction(ReceiveSocket, recvbuflen); } };
    inputThread.join();
    receiveThread.join();

    std::cout << 14 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int sendFunction(char *sendbuf, SOCKET ConnectionSocket)
{
    int iResult;
    // Send an initial buffer
    std::cout << 10 << std::endl;

    if (ConnectionSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        std::cout << 17 << std::endl;

    iResult = send(ConnectionSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    std::cout << 18 << std::endl;
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << 11 << std::endl;
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectionSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << 16 << std::endl;

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    return 0;
}

int shutdownFunction(SOCKET ConnectSocket)
{
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    std::cout << 12 << std::endl;
    int iResult;
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int receiveFunction(SOCKET ConnectSocket, int recvbuflen)
{
    char *recvContent = new char[recvbuflen];
    int iResult;
    std::cout << 20 << std::endl;
    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        std::cout << 13 << std::endl;
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvContent, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)
            {
                std::cout << recvContent[i];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            printf("Connection closed\n");
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            shutdownFunction(ConnectSocket);
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    return 0;
}

int inputFunction(char *sendbuf, SOCKET ConnectSocket)
{
    std::cout << 15 << std::endl;

    std::string temp;
    while (true)
    {
        getline(std::cin, temp);
        sendbuf = new char[temp.length() + 1];

        strncpy(sendbuf, temp.c_str(), temp.length());
        sendbuf[temp.length()] = '\0';

        std::thread sendThread{ [sendbuf, ConnectSocket](){sendFunction(sendbuf, ConnectSocket); } };
        sendThread.join();
        delete[] sendbuf;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As ports, I use 1016 through 1020. I already tried changing them but it didn't change anything. As ip address, I use 127.0.0.1.
Something that I also dont really understand is why in my accept function, it doesn't print out 12 and 13 as it is supposed to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

mindoo

Comment: You're only accepting one connection and then exiting the `accept()` thread. Working as designed.

Comment: @EJP I understand what your saying but normally my loop should re iterate calling a getaddrinfo with anoter port and the launching the accept thread for that socket. And do you have any idea why it doesn't print out 12 and 13 ?

Comment: Your accept thread should loop accepting connections on the same socket. You don't need to keep creating new sockets to listen to.

Comment: @EJP So if I understand correctly, I do not need to keep on using getaddr info with different ports ? All I have to do is listen on the same socket ?

Comment: @EJP And what about the cout problem, do you have any idea why that doesn't work ?

Comment: What part of 'same socket' don't you understand? And what happened to the alleged '`cout` problem' when you fixed this?

Comment: First of all I dont know why you are so hostile. Aren't we all on this site to learn in any sort of way ? Second of all, I tried doing what You said and it still didn't work. I'll post my updated code in an edit of my question.